# Migrate Neo4j single instance to cluster

Tags: neo4j

at the moment our project runs a single instance Neo4j Enterprise 4.4.11 from the according helm chart version 4.4.10. We already have some data there, which can't be simply re-created.
We have the licenses so we plan to switch to a three core cluster setup of the same version. No analysis if we can update the DB alone without the according application code. According to compatibility matrix of the driver, yes but not tested.

The interesting part at the moment is: How to migrate the data to the cluster? I did not find any according documentation at neo's website. Can I simply change the config of the single instance and tell it "you're a cluster member now"? May be copy the data folder?

Any help is highly appreciated. Hopefully someone did something similar already in the past and give me a hint. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, it is possible to simply restore the cluster members from the single instance backup.
I first created an online backup from the single instance, of course made sure there are no changes incoming in the meantime. Then removed the single instance and created the infrastructure for the cluster. Each cluster member has a custom init container which brings the instance onto the status of the last backup. All three cluster members restored from the same backup, formed the cluster and synced themselves. To complete the setup, the cluster got an headless service running in front of it. The headless service provides the routing between cluster members and application. Is also available as helm chart from neo.